# Sonar not finding dependencies in sonar.api.resources

Tags: java, dependencies, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm attempting to run static analysis on my project using sonar runner but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.RunnerException: org.picocontainer.i
njectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: org.sonar.api.reso
urces.Languages has unsatisfied dependency 'class [Lorg.sonar.api.resources.Lang
uage;' for constructor 'public org.sonar.api.resources.Languages(org.sonar.api.r
esources.Language[])' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@15c13ef:34<[Im
mutable]:org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@1865b28:206<[Immutable]:org.pico
container.DefaultPicoContainer@8d5a91:18<|
......
...
.
```

My sonar-project.properties:

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=smstomb:myProject
sonar.projectName=My Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# optional description
sonar.projectDescription=This is my project

# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=src/main

# path to test source directories (optional)
sonar.tests=src/test

sonar.libraries=lib/*.jar

sonar.language=java

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

This is a fresh install and I've not downloaded any additional plugins on the sonar-server.

Comment: Can you please detail the versions that you are using? (Sonar, SonarRunner, ...etc) The error you got is weird and you shouldn't have this if you simply installed the latest versions of Sonar and Sonar Runner.

Comment: sonar runner: 2.0 | sonar: 3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

The message you got tends to say that your Sonar install is corrupted: no language plugin has been installed, whereas the Sonar distribution (= the ZIP file) comes with the Java ecosystem by default. (you can have a look at the "/extensions/plugin" folder and check that you have the Java plugins installed)

To make it simple, the best would be to make a new fresh install again.